# Getting a 403 ERROR with DELETE REQUEST - HYBRIS

Tags: spring, spring-security, sap-commerce-cloud, http-delete

I am trying to call the method deleteSaveCartForId in AccountSavedCartsPageController :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{cartId}/delete", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@RequireHardLogIn
public @ResponseBody String deleteSaveCartForId(@PathVariable(value = "cartId") final String cartId)
        throws CommerceSaveCartException
```

but I am getting a

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (forbidden)
```

I think maybe the answer could be in the spring-security-config.xml file but I don't see where could be the parameter to change.
Or maybe the answer it's totally somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

If given cart related with other items (for example order, order item, cart item), it can be give error like this. Hybris cannot support CASCADE delete in ORM level for some case. I don't have information about given rest method has this functionality. You need to check hybris error log. Maybe you need enable debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the @RequireHardLogin annotation. Maybe this annotation interferes with your request? Check RequireHardLoginBeforeControllerHandler and RequireHardLoginEvaluator.

If that does not help: How do you call the method? AJAX? Web service? What is the URL you are calling? Maybe you miss the context path? Extension root?